# javascript - "undefined" values from regex exec

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm begginer.  I want to put indexes of searched string (regex + exec) into array after pressing "RUN" button. I musing arr.push.  I have problem inside while loop - probably because of closures. I get array [undefinde, undefined.....]. The string is taken from textarea.value

Look at the JSFiddle code
http://jsfiddle.net/andre81/eXrQq/8/

```
function TrimReport () {
    'use strict';
        var ReportTxt = document.getElementById('RaportInput');
        var Str = ReportTxt.value;  

        var re = /\<tr\>/gmi;
        var result = [];
        var val;        
        var match;
        var div = document.getElementById('output');

        while (match = re.exec(Str)) {
            val =  match.index; 
            result.push(val.lastIndex);
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + val + '<br>';
            //console.log(match.index);
        };
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + result + '<br>';
        //console.log(result);
};


//Initial function:
function init() {
    'use strict';
      if(document && document.getElementById) {
            var bttn = document.getElementById('RUN');
            bttn.onclick = TrimReport;
      } //if end
    //alert('inside init');
    //console.log('inside init');
}//init end
window.onload = init;
```

HTML code:

```
  <div id="input">
    <textarea cols="160" rows="18" id="RaportInput">
 <!-- IMPORTED CONTENT inside TEXTAREA -->       
<p><center><h1>  Revit Coordination Report  </h1></center></p>
<p><center><h2>  In a linked project  </h2></center></p>
<p><table border=on>  <tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floor opening cut  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  : (Deleted element ) : id = -1  <br>  SEG06 : Floor opening cut : Opening Cut : id 1060252  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floor opening cut  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  : (Deleted element ) : id = -1  <br>  SEG06 : Floor opening cut : Opening Cut : id 1060259  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floor opening cut  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  : (Deleted element ) : id = -1  <br>  SEG06 : Floor opening cut : Opening Cut : id 1061236  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floor opening cut  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  : (Deleted element ) : id = -1  <br>  SEG11 : Floor opening cut : Opening Cut : id 1549469  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floors  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  : (Deleted element ) : id = -1  <br>  SEG11 : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 1549457  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floors  </td>  <td>  Maintain Floor elevations  </td>  <td>  Floor elevation changed  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : RVT_Links : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 2367719  <br>  SEG08 : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 332807  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floors  </td>  <td>  Maintain Floor elevations  </td>  <td>  Floor elevation changed  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : RVT_Links : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 2378060  <br>  SEG04 : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 997351  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floors  </td>  <td>  Monitor Floor Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : RVT_Links : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 2378060  <br>  SEG04 : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 997351  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floors  </td>  <td>  Monitor Floor Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : External_Walls : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 2723982  <br>  SEG13 : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 1775643  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floors  </td>  <td>  Monitor new Floor openings  </td>  <td>  New Openings Detected in 'Floor : h=28cm'  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : RVT_Links : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 2378060  <br>  SEG04 : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 997351  <br>  SEG04 : Floor opening cut : Opening Cut : id 1808079  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Floors  </td>  <td>  Monitor new Floor openings  </td>  <td>  New Openings Detected in 'Floor : h=28cm'  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : External_Walls : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 2723982  <br>  SEG13 : Floors : Floor : h=28cm : id 1775643  <br>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Shafts : Shaft Openings : Opening Cut : id 1203484  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : RVT_Links : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_wall box section_400 : id 2356962  <br>  : (Deleted element ) : id = 1597600  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  : (Deleted element ) : id = -1  <br>  SEG10 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-300mm : id 1761197  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  : (Deleted element ) : id = -1  <br>  SEG13 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-300mm : id 1773182  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  : (Deleted element ) : id = -1  <br>  SEG13 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1773190  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Check whether an Element exists  </td>  <td>  Element deleted  </td>  <td>  : (Deleted element ) : id = -1  <br>  SEG13 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1773202  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Maintain wall elevation/height  </td>  <td>  Wall Elevations are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Structural_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_300 : id 1834524  <br>  SEG04 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-300mm : id 996843  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_300 : id 2643467  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-300mm : id 1650596  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643508  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1656518  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643510  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1657659  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643511  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1657688  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketch is missing  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643512  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1657947  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketch is missing  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643513  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1657965  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643514  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1657979  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643515  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1657989  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643516  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1657999  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketch is missing  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643517  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1658013  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketch is missing  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2643518  <br>  SEG06 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1658027  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketch is missing  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : Internal_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_300 : id 2643611  <br>  SEG10 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-300mm : id 1760438  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  New/Unresolved  </td>  <td>  Walls  </td>  <td>  Monitor Wall Sketches  </td>  <td>  Sketches are different  </td>  <td>  P1218_WOOD_ARCHITEKTURA.rvt : External_Walls : Walls : Basic Wall : konstrukcja_sc_250 : id 2723649  <br>  SEG13 : Walls : Basic Wall : Sc-250mm : id 1727350  </td>  <td>    </td>  </tr>
</table>

    </textarea>
  </div>

<button type="button" id="RUN">RUN</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: try `console.log(val.lastIndex)` you are trying to push, is it defined?

Comment: also why did you try to sneak load a script named "m.js" hidden in this fiddle? Did you attempt to hack or something?

Comment: Add your expected output also

Comment: @Winchestro -  console.log(val.lastIndex) gives me  _'undefined'_ but still I don't know why. I've found solution posted below but still I'm not happy with my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple related errors in your `while` loop. See [documentation on the RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function to see how to use it correctly. The most immediate errors are:

1. `val` is an integer (i.e., the "0-based index of the match in the string"), not an object.
2. The `lastIndex` property actually belongs to the `re` object.

See the link I provided above for an example of how to loop correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the script below just before the body tag / use Dom Ready.

Demo: [`JS Fiddle Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/eXrQq/16/)

The above technique to avoid Dom Ready Method which will increase performance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/ * You code */
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer should be spelled out here in StackOverflow.  You can use the jsFiddle link to enhance your answer, but not as your only explanatory part of the answer.

Comment: I agree with your point, here i have never changed the code to share it, only mentioned the technique, Any way i have mentioned the code to get a hint. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. I've changed:

```
 result.push(val.lastIndex);
```

to:

```
result.push(val);
```

inside while loop. It seems to work fine but I'm still not satisfied with my knowledge.
I put corrected code here:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andre81/aA4d7/3/)

@Venkat
My expected output of this script is to take this HTML table: 
 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andre81/Z9Qt2/2/) and slice it according to COLUMNS's categories and ID's and put them int ARRAYS. Example like those:

```
[Floors, Monitor Floor Sketches, [id 1775643, id 997351,  id 1652983, .....]]    
[Floors, Monitor new Floor openings , [ id 997351, id 997351,  id 1652343, .....]]  
[Walls, Maintain wall position , [ id 997351, id 997351,  id 1652978, .....]]
```

and so on....

[category, category, [id 1, id 2, id 3,...]]

Only thing - I will not put "id" prefix in those arrays.
All this Arrays I will use in Revit softwere for elements selection by ID - write in YouTube 
"revit id selection"  (I cannot give more than two links...)